# SQL Server Query Performance Deterioration

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I currently utilize a financial database which my company pays access for (CapitalIQ - Xpressfeed) and it allows us to get a replicated version of their DB once a night which I then host on a AWS instance and query.

The queries I have to run are pretty long and require joins on many different tables (8-10 tables which are quiet large) which causes each query to have an runtime of ~20-30 seconds.

My systems processes 700 queries (one for each of our clients) and when the system starts the queries run properly at 20-30 second each. The problem occurs after the 7th query runs which, without fail, increases the query runtime to ~2 minutes per.

If I shut down the code used to query the database, wait a few minutes, then start it back up the queries again revert back to ~20-30 seconds, only to later increase to ~2 minutes after a few of the queries have been run.

Some important notes - these queries are select only - I am not updating or any other type of function so this is not some issue where I am accuring data throughout.

Has anyone ever had issues like this? I know there are many different areas to look at (I/O problems, memory issues, etc.), however I am just baffled by the fact that the queries run fine for the first queries but then something is built up internally at the DB that causes a bottle neck and back-log.

Comment: Is there anything different about that query? Such as different parameters, different query text (even comments)? Have you compared the execution plan? We can't guess based on nothing: please give us the relevant queries, tables and indexes, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: There's simply not enough info here to suggest anything. You need to start by analysing the waits of the running queries and see what they are waiting on compared to running faster, do they reuse the same cached plan etc

Comment: Start by turning on the Query Store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=%20Use%20the%20Query%20Store%20Page%20in%20SQL,Mode%20%28Requested%29%20box%2C%20select%20Read%20Write.%20See%20More.